# Unable to send the modern page's Description inside an email using Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

I am working on a classic team online site collection, and i implemented a workflow 2013, to send the modern page Description once it is been updated/published (Promoted State = 2), here is what i did:-

[image]

but currently the description will be trimmed out inside the email body. not sure how i can show it full with all the pictures and tables? there is an option to "Retrun field as: Plain text", but i do not want to send plain text.
Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Automate (Microsoft Flow), instead of a 2013 workflow.  You are artificially limiting yourself with a SharePoint 2013 workflow.